# Is it likely that Christianity was born from Judaism?

Tags: judaism, jerusalem

The History timeline of Jerusalem states that the first monotheism in Jerusalem was Judaism, then Christianity followed. So it's likely that Christianity evolved from Judaism.

Did Jesus Christ take some ideas from Judaism to create Christianity? 
if not, why those 2 religious are so similar? The new would probably learned and upgraded some of the useful things from the old to create its own version.

I don't know much more about religions.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows not even the slightest hint of any research effort. The simplest google search would answer this question.

Comment: -1 for a complete and utter lack of research effort. Read [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christianity#History). The very first sentence in the linked section answers your question. How someone can know enough about Judaism and about Christianity individually, to recognize that they have some similarities, and not know the slightest about Christian history to answer this question completely baffles me, and makes me think this question is a potential troll.

Comment: I'd say that, as basic a question this is, it should stay open.  The site does try to focus on expert questions, but this is a fair question for someone with no background at all, and it is ***easily*** answerable.  Someone with skill could put a very top-notch, answer to this.  Do you really want to close a question just because it's "easy to answer"?  Many highly-rated questions on StackOverflow could be answered with a quick google search? ([Example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10643379/how-do-i-query-for-all-dates-greater-than-a-certain-date-in-sql-server/10643403#10643403))

Comment: @David OK I'll take up the challenge - sometimes a question that looks too easy can be hard to answer.

Comment: Meanwhile, welcome to Christianity.SE! For a quick overview of what this site is about, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour). And if in the future you want to ask questions here that won't attract downvotes, please see: [How do I ask a good question?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)
I do hope you'll stick around, and spend some time browsing the questions and answers here.

Comment: @David: Some questions are too simple for SE, IMO.  The down-vote button says "This question does not show any research." That's obviously true of this question. If the question deserves, by the definition of "down vote", to get one, it seems it probably deserves to be closed. At least it's hard for me to imagine a question that *ought* to be down-voted, but ought *not* be closed.

Comment: @David: Further, if we're going to allow this question, why not allow "Is Christ another common name for Jesus?" and "Is it true that Christianity got its name from Jesus Christ?" and "Do Christians generally believe the Bible is the word of God?" and "Is it true that Christians believe God created the universe?" and a plethora of other kindergarten sunday shcool level questions?

Comment: @Flimzy - My initial response to this was in the spirit of [this post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/07/kicking-off-the-summer-of-love/)  it's hard to participate in this site even for experienced users... A first time user with a really basic question, give the OP the benefit of the doubt, and guide them along.  With the second question the OP asked, I'm less likely to believe that these are honest questions.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, Christianity was born out of Judaism.  Jesus was, as far as we know, born in Bethlehem, near Jerusalem, and was crucified in Jerusalem and on the third day rose from the dead.

Judaism may not have been the first monotheistic religion in the Near East - Zoroastrianism may have a valid claim to that distinction - but it remains monotheistic, as does Christianity. The scriptures of the Jewish religion, known to Jews as the Tanach, became scriptures of Christianity, known as the Old Testament, to which were added the Christian New Testament scriptures. Although Jesus did not actually say that Christians should use the scriptures that now form the Old Testament, he did say that he came to fulfil the law of the Jews.

The Judaism that Jesus knew was not the rabbinic Judaism we know today. What we call Second Temple Judaism ended in 70 CE with the destruction of the great temple in Jerusalem.  Christianity and rabbinic Judaism both came out of Second Temple Judaism, and each offered a new way forward, for those who believed in God. John Dominic Crossan says, in the Prologue to *[The Birth of Christianity](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/76888.The_Birth_of_Christianity)*, Christianity and rabbinic Judaism each claimed exclusive continuity with the past, but in truth each was as great a leap and as valid a development from that common ancestry as was the other. Crossan describes Christianity and rabbinic Judaism as like two children of the same mother.